# mysql query with match and against with AND or OR

Tags: mysql

Is possible to optimize the queries?

I have a db with id, title, description, keywords as columns, I need to query and have result in relevant order.

I need to use more keywords, should I use AND or OR or to build the query in other way?

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth AND food AND money'
             IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS SCORE 
FROM _table 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth AND food AND money'
             IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

or

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth OR food OR money'
             IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS SCORE 
FROM _table 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth OR food OR money'
             IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

or?

thanks

Comment: my query will contain more keywords, in the eample i udes 3 but probably I'll use 5 to 30 keywords.

Comment: Those are different queries. One returns results containing all of the keywords, the other returns results containing one or more of the keywords. Use the one which returns the correct result you expect.

Comment: I need all possible results, the second.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the search words with the characters provided in the link

MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which

```
+ stands for AND

- stands for NOT

[no operator] implies OR
```

For more information see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

So your first query would be

```
SELECT 
    *,
    MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+earth +food +money' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS SCORE
FROM
    _videvotradotto
WHERE
    MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+earth +food +money' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

and the second

```
SELECT 
    *,
    MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth food money' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS SCORE
FROM
    _videvotradotto
WHERE
    MATCH (title) AGAINST ('earth food money' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 question: both queries give me same number of results (720 of 50000)  If I query SELECT * FROM `_table` WHERE titleen LIKE '%earth%' OR titleen LIKE '%food%' OR titleen LIKE '%money' I get 665 results, if I query SELECT * FROM `_table` WHERE titleen LIKE '%earth%' OR '%food%' OR '%money' i get 362 results. 

In the manual, regarding boolean: "They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance".

Comment: you should try the other modes like Boolean, natural lanuguage mode is a bit fuzzy that is why it has more results than the ORs. in the manual you find also a section for optimizing, that is vera central to understand  Full text search your other question refers to the definition of a result set it is unsorted by nature , that is why you need to add an ORDER BY

Comment: Where is the part of the manual for optimising?

Comment: you have to read the hole link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 0):

"earthworm" and "dearth" were included in the `LIKE`.  So `LIKE gives you extra words.

(I cannot explain why the larger "720" occurred.)  Consider trying `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

You should really look at the documents to observe both of these "anomalies", and possibly other anomalies.

Meanwhile, 'AND' and 'OR' are probably "stop words".  This means that they were ignored.  (One would hope that "the" is ignored in English!)

Meanwhile, nbk explains how to do AND and OR in FULLTEXT.

Comment: Thanks Rick James. Where do you get that IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE runs a second query based on other words found in the first pass?

Comment: @fedep11 - My bad.  I was thinking about `WITH QUERY EXPANSION`.